# NULLify CTRL press in link clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement in preventing the links in my applications from spilling over to new window/tab through CTRL keys. I have the following in my page now:

```
        $(document).click(function(e)
        {
            if (e.ctrlKey)
            {
                return (false);
            }
        });
```

This seems to be working fine for DIV clicks however link clicks are totally ignored. I am looking to see if I can NULLIfy the CTRL keypress alone and make it appear like simple click. Is that possible? A  kind of forcing the event keyCode for ctrl alone to be zero?

Comment: You could stop the event and dispatch a new one without the ctrl key.

Comment: Why do you know better than your users whether they should open that link in a tab or not?

Comment: How can this be a requirement? There are so many ways to open links in a new tab...

Comment: A very popular ticket booking site doesn't allow opening new instance of the site in another tab by control clicking. It is for the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) return false;
});
```

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gTG6Q/

*Note:* The user can still right click and open your link in a new tab. For preventing that, you will need to negate the `contextmenu` event as well.

Answer (score 1):

By "document", plus elements that may later be added via AJAX, using this simple one-liner:-
Copy code

```
$(document).on("click", "*", function(e)  { 
    if (e.ctrlKey) return false; 
});
```

If you're version of jQuery is lower than v1.7 then use .live() instead of .on() (just change the word from "on" to "live").